ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolov7'
I am trying out code in this repository.
I run one of the command given in their readme page, but I am getting ModuleNotFoundError:
/workspace/BoTSORT$ python3 tools/mc_demo_yolov7.py --weights pretrained/mot17_sbs_S50.pth --source /workspace/datasets/videos/seq1/seq1_florida_00-15-50_00-16-05.mp4 --fuse-score --agnostic-nms --with-reid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/mc_demo_yolov7.py", line 14, in <module>
    from yolov7.models.experimental import attempt_load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolov7'

Here is ls command output:
/workspace/BoTSORT$ ls
LICENSE    VideoCameraCorrection  assets    fast_reid   requirements.txt  setup.py            tools    yolov7
README.md  YOLOX_outputs          datasets  pretrained  setup.cfg         start_container.sh  tracker  yolox

So, yolov7 folder does indeed exist in the directory /workspace/BoTSORT.
One thing I noticed that it does not contain __init__.py. So I tried adding one in /workspace/BoTSORT/yolov7 directory with the following content (similar to /workspace/BoTSORT/yolox/__init__.py directory):
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from .models import *
__version__ = "0.1.0"

But no help, am still getting the same error.
PS:
I am running inside docker container. But I believe this does not have any effect that can cause the given error.

I am running inside docker container Is the ls output you showed also from inside the docker container?

Yup. It's from inside docker only. Also want to point out that there was similar question for same repository here. But the answer there is really not satisfactory.

Your main script is tools/mc_demo_yolov7.py. If PYTHONPATH environment variable wasn't modified and sys.path wasn't  modified in the Python code and /workspace/BoTSORT wasn't added to the search path by other means, Python won't search there.
